# Spock test case doesn't work without JUnit's @Test annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spock

I have started new java 11, spring boot 2.3.1 project in IntelliJ.
I wanted to add spock to dependencies however I am facing a problem when trying to run example test case.

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.example.SpockSpec':
1. No runnable methods
```

This is list of my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovyVersion"
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0'
}
```

(groovy version is 3.0.0)

this is the spec:

```
class SpockSpec extends Specification {

    def "result should be true"(){
        given:
        boolean a = false;
        boolean b = true;

        when:
        boolean result = a || b;

        then:
        result == true;
    }
}
```

Workaround is to add JUnit's @Test annotation before the method but I would prefer not to do that.
Also - when I do so testing only works when I run whole class.

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock 1 is based on JUnit 4, but Spock 2 runs on the JUnit 5 platform, implementing its own engine (not JUnit Jupiter). So maybe you want to first read some documentation and then upgrade to JUnit 5 (not vintage). Right on top of the manual in chapter "getting started" there is a subchapter ["Spock example project"](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M2/all_in_one.html#_spock_example_project).